# C : why local variable is modifying with sprintf?

Tags: c, asprintf

consider this example. I created a local scoped buffer below which can store 2 characters and one terminator. But when I cross that thresold with 2 digits number i.e a = 20 then something weird happens when I call sprintf. a gets modified and prints out 0. If I change buff size from 3 to 4. variable a doesn't change. what is this frustrating behaviour? I am using clang 13.0.0 compiler.

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    
  
    int a = 20;
    {
        char buff[3];
        sprintf(buff, "a%d", a);
    }
    printf("value of a %d",a);
    
    return 0;
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Overflowing buffers results in Undefined Behaviour. C doesn't stop you from doing that and anything after that point is undefined. So it's your job as a programmer to ensure that doesn't occur.

Comment: Have a look to snprintf.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have corrupted the buffer. So it will result in Undefined Behaviour.

The size of the buffer pointed by `buff` is only 3 bytes. `sprintf(buff, "a%d", a);` writes 4 bytes to it. Because `a` is also on the stack, it gets being corrupted.